# Touching a Button should open a new DropDown. Even possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, drop-down-menu

Well, I have a `Button` on my Window.
The following describes what I would like to do:

Touching the Button with the Mouse (I assume, the best event would be `MouseMove`), should open a new **DropDown** at the Button. (Something similiar like a *Combobox* DropDown)

*This Dropdown will be filled with data, and each item is an event (item will show the name of the event as string in the DropDown), which calls a method that I'm at the other hand determining over Reflection.*

What I actually would like to know, is, if it is even possible, to accomplish this task?

Creating a new DropDown at or beside the button, when the user touches the Button with the Mouse?
How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Context Menu and display it on the buttons Mouse Enter Event.
See [MSDN ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22c1dx6k%28v=vs.71%29) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For touch I think the closest event is mouse enter and mouse leave.   And could you not just have a ComboBox or ListBox and manipulate the visibility (on the mouse enter and mouse leave events).  For mouse leave would need to be on panel with both the button and DropDown.

Answer (score 1):

The [Extended Wpf Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) got something like that:

[DropDownButton](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DropDownButton)